# Whose hand gets cut off in Ant-Man?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

Every single MCU Phase 2 film has featured a character getting their hand cut off, [in a deliberate nod to Star Wars](http://ign.com/articles/2015/04/22/how-marvel-sneaked-a-star-wars-reference-into-its-phase-2-movies), and Kevin Feige has said that Ant-Man is no exception. I saw Ant-Man with my friend over the weekend, but I forgot to look for the Easter egg at the time and now I can't recall where it was. I hate to say it, but...

Can someone please give me a hand? :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No one's hand gets cut off in *Ant-Man*. The closest thing we get is;

> When Darren Cross (Yellowjacket) is being killed after Scott goes sub-molecular in order to stop him, his arms is destroyed/implodes first.

This is the closest thing we get to the idea of a hand being cut off in *Ant Man*.

Also, it's worth noting that it isn't just the phase 2 films that contain scenes where a character loses a hand. Both *Daredevil* and season 2 of *Agents of SHIELD* contain a character losing a hand.

Answer (score 21):

There's another possible answer. Towards the end, as Scott and the flying ants chase the helicopter,

> Anthony is shot and his severed wing flutters to the ground.

Answer (score 13):

It's very subtle, and happens at the end of the movie:

> When Scott disables the Yellowjacket suit, the first thing that happens is Darren's hand is crushed and disappears, several seconds before the rest of him.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an arm-loss scene:

> Yellowjacket/Darren Cross loses his right arm as he is dying/crushed into his own suit.